# Can YouTube IDs be reissued after a video is deleted?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Suppose I have a video on YouTube that gets the URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWSyMuKkXXX (not a real video/ID, fwiw).  If I delete that video, what are the chances that "vWSyMuKkXXX" will get reassigned to another video that somebody else puts up?  62^11 (is that right?) is a pretty large space from which to be assigning symbols, but YouTube must be doing some uniqueness test to avoid duplicates.  The question, I guess, would then be whether they're including deleted IDs in that test (at least, given the way I'm guessing what they're doing internally).

This question is all about how much work I have to do to figure out whether the video corresponding to an ID exists and that it is the video that I think it is -- whether I can get away with using a simple call to http://www.youtube.com/oembed?... , or whether I need to get authentication and the APIs involved (which might still not resolve the question).  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If YouTube were to ever reuse IDs, it would cause problems such as old links now pointing to new (possibly unlisted) videos. There is no advantage in reusing IDs, only problems including privacy problems. It would be an ugly bug.

To support unlisted videos, the IDs cannot be sequential. They must come from a large space of possible values.

> how much work I have to do to figure out whether the video corresponding to an ID exists

You must send a query to YouTube.

> and that it is the video that I think it is

How do you define "the video that I think it is"? By ID? By watching the transcoded video at your current resolution -- where the individual pixels might not match the uploaded pixels?